# how to get the value of a dynamically created textbox on buttonclick

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have created two dynamic tables and textboxes like this:

```
protected void drpNetworkList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string socialNetworkName = drpNetworkList.SelectedItem.Text;

DataSet networkdata =   VoCServiceObj.GetSocailNetworkNameDetails(partnerid,socialNetworkName);           

        int cdount = networkdata.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

            pnlViewData.Controls.Clear();
            Check.Checked = true;               
            pnlViewData.Visible = true;
            table = new Table();
            table.ID = "tbl_dy";

            //Brandurl
            row = new TableRow();
            cell = new TableCell();

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "lbl_1";
            lbl.Text = "BrandURL";
            cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = "textBox";
            txt.Text = networkdata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BrandDestinationURL"].ToString();
            cell.Controls.Add(txt);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            for (int i = 1; i <= cdount; i++)
            {
                int count = i - 1;

                //ProdutId
                row = new TableRow();
                cell = new TableCell();

                Label lbl2 = new Label();
                lbl2.ID = "lbl_1'" + i + "'";
                lbl2.Text = "ProductID" + i + "'";
                cell.Controls.Add(lbl2);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableCell();
                TextBox txt2 = new TextBox();
                txt2.ID = "textBox1" + i + "'";
                txt2.Text = networkdata.Tables[0].Rows[count]["ProductID"].ToString();
                cell.Controls.Add(txt2);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                table.Rows.Add(row);

                //ProdutURL
                row = new TableRow();
                cell = new TableCell();

                Label lbl3 = new Label();
                lbl3.ID = "lbl_2'" + i + "'";
                lbl3.Text = "ProductURL" + i + "'";
                cell.Controls.Add(lbl3);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                cell = new TableCell();
                TextBox txt3 = new TextBox();
                txt3.ID = "textBox2" + i + "'";
                txt3.Text = networkdata.Tables[0].Rows[count]["ProductDestinationURL"].ToString();
                cell.Controls.Add(txt3);
                row.Cells.Add(cell);

                table.Rows.Add(row);

            }
            pnlViewData.Controls.Add(table);

    }
   protected void imgSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
                    TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("textBox11");
        String str = string.Empty;
        str = tb1.Text;
    }
```

The textboxes display a default value coming from the database.I am editing these values in runtime and i want to get these values in a button click function.
How  do i achieve this???

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

All page controls are created every time when the page is created.

Controls created dynamically on events have to be recreated on the next `Init`.

Only controls created before `ProcessPostData` can receive data entered by the users.

You can use the `ViewState` to remember that these controls have to be recreated next time.